# Can not access control from nested master page in content page

Tags: asp.net, master-pages

I am using nested master pages where i want to use `Label` control from nested master page and update its text. but it is not accessing. When i removed outer master page then it is working fine. Following is the markup and code.

**OUTER MASTER**

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Site.master.cs" Inherits="Roster.Site" %>
```

**NESTED MASTER**

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="RoasterMaster.master.cs" Inherits="Roster.RoasterMaster"  MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" %>
<%@ MasterType VirtualPath ="~/Site.Master" %>
```

**CONTENT PAGE**

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" Inherits="RequestsView" CodeBehind="ViewRequestsByPM.aspx.cs" MasterPageFile ="~/Roaster/RoasterMaster.Master" Title ="Roaster- View Requests by PM" %>
<%@ MasterType VirtualPath ="~/Roaster/RoasterMaster.Master" %>
```

**CONTENT PAGE CODE**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{


    Label lblTitle = new Label();

    lblTitle =(Label)Master.FindControl("lblTitle");
    lblTitle.Text = "View Roaster Request";
}
```

What is going wrong with the implementation. Please help. Thanks

Comment: Do you know how to use public properties? this would be a much better way of setting / getting the labels value

Comment: you have to find the specific masterpage by using something master.master or page.master first which contains the control "lblTitle"

Comment: There are specific markups on the page '<%@ MasterType VirtualPath ="..." %>'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add the below code snippet in

NESTED MASTER PAGE

```
public string PageTitle { get; set; } // In page_load
lblTitle.Text = PageTitle;
```

CONTENT PAGE CODE

```
this.Master.PageTitle = "YOUR TEXT";
```

This will work for you...

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your label is in Roster master page, you can simply add method to set the text in master page code behind. For example,

in *RoasterMaster.master.cs*

```
public void SetTitle(string value)
{
   this.lblTitle = value;
}
```

And in content page code

```
Master.SetTitle("View Roaster Request");
```

In case, your label is in outer master then you can similarly forward the call to the outer master from roster master code.

**EDIT**
Your code does not work in nested master case scenarios because Master page contents get added within page control hierarchy with different naming container. `FindControl` method does not span multiple naming containers which is the case here - because of nesting you have nested naming containers. `Page.Master` would give you outer naming container but your label might be lying in inner naming container. One of the way, is to write your own find control implementation that will recurs within the control tree but really it does not make sense - I would rather use above code which is more efficient and more importantly better maintainable.